# C# XAML page dependency injection on the fly with MVVM Light

Tags: xaml, mvvm, uwp, mvvm-light, uwp-xaml

I would like some feedback to see if I'm using SimpleIoc in the correct way.
The code below works, but I'm not sure if it's best practice.

I have an UWP XAML `DocumentPage` class on which I want to show an `IRpcDocument`.

I want to use the `DocumentPage` for both `RpcDocumentA` and `RpcDocumentB`. The user can navigate to both types of IRpcDocument. So the application should be able to switch between the two 'on the fly'.

So I wrote my `DocumentPageViewModel`

```
public class DocumentPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public IRpcDocument RpcDocument;

    public DocumentPageViewModel(IRpcDocument rpcDocument)
    {
        RpcDocument = rpcDocument;
    }
}
```

And my ViewModelLocator

```
class ViewModelLocator
{
    static ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<DocumentPageViewModel>(); 
    }

    public DocumentPageViewModel SimpleIoc.Default.Register<DocumentPageViewModel>
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<SimpleIoc.Default.Register<DocumentPageViewModel>>(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

When I'm navigating to the `DocumentPage` I call:

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IRpcDocument , RpcDocumentA>();
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync(typeof(DocumentPage), DocumentIdParameter);
```

The app then navigates to the `DocumentPage`, constructs the RpcDocumentA, makes the necessary RPC calls to fetch the data and shows the document.

The first line tells the IoC framework it should expect an RpcDocumentA in its constructor, the second one triggers navigation. So in this case, im not registering the interface in the static ViewModelLocator().

So for each time I navigate I call `SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IRpcDocument , RpcDocumentA>` or `SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IRpcDocument , RpcDocumentB>`

This works, but is this the right way to do this? I suspect it's not.

Comment: Could you please tell the consideration you have that  why you suspect it is not a right way? And please also provide the code of `IRpcDocument` interface  to let us have a testing on our side.

Comment: How will you tell your app that you want to navigate to RpcDocumentB? Is there a logic before calling SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IRpcDocument , RpcDocumentA>()?